# Joint density function of Y = X^2

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Can someone please help me solve this exercise:

[image]

I know how to plot the joint density of the $X$1$,$$...$$,$$X$n since it is just the product of each individual density function of each of the $X$i random variables since they are independent. However, I don't know how to plot the joint density function of the $Y$i! Should I just substitute the $x$$^2$ by $y$? Although I don't believe that is correct since I have seen certain examples where the Jacobian comes in! Please tell me what to do!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hints

- find the CDF of $X_1$ (on e.g. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rayleigh_distribution))
- deduce from that the CDF of $Y_1=X_1^2$
- deduce the PDF of $Y_1$ as derivative of the CDF of $Y_1$
- be aware that also the $Y_i$ are independent.